# how can i do cross site scripting in javascript in my own browser (Firefox)

Tags: firefox, javascript

I was watching a Video Tutorial on a website. The Videos are hosted on platform.thinkific.com. The videos were made in light theme whereas I like Dark Theme so I inverted the color of Video using the `filter: invert(90%)` property. But finding the video element each time and applying this property manually was very cumbersome so i wrote a script. But it gives me this problem : `Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object`

i know that this error is coming because of the security measures my browser took. But as I am running this in my browser I think I can disable this feature somehow. I am actually writing a bookmarklet to perform this action automatically. So my question was how can i do it? or is there a way to make it work or automate this workflow?

I wrote the script as follows:

```js
var iframedoc = document.getElementById("iframe-ember5848");
var innerdoc = iframedoc.contentDocument || iframedoc.contentWindow.document;
var video=innerdoc.querySelector("#wistia_video video");
video.style.filter=="invert(90%)"?video.style.filter="":video.style.filter="invert(90%)";
```

I am using Firefox on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Comment: This seems to be a programming question better suited to [so]. Please read [help/on-topic]

Comment: This is related to Firefox Browser not with the JavaScript itself. And I have seen another answer for [IE](https://superuser.com/questions/757265/how-can-i-use-bookmarklets-in-ie11-that-involve-cross-site-scripting) which is for windows users but not for linux users.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no control over the iframe and you're trying to interact with it using JavaScript, you're limited by the Same-Origin Policy, which restricts cross-origin access for security reasons.

Supposing that you're in that situation, you need something more than JS, however you can considerate to create a server side reverse proxy.

A quick setup can be made with [Express](https://expressjs.com/), you can find plenty of examples on the net.

Good luck!